# What is the point of the Common Language Runtime (CLR)?

Tags: virtual-machine, clr

My understanding is that part of the point of the JVM was that the code could "run anywhere", but CLR code was designed to run only on Windows: so why have a virtual machine?

I know that the CLR runtime takes care of garbage collection, but there are garbage-collected languages that still compile to native code.

The only thing I can think of is that Microsoft may have wanted leverage in order to keep the price of Intel chips low.

Comment: `The only thing I can think of is that Microsoft may have wanted leverage in order to keep the price of Intel chips low.` -- Nice, but no.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime#Benefits

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks for the link, but couldn't those benefits be achieved in other ways without sharing a virtual machine?

Comment: Perhaps, but why would you bother looking for other ways when the CLR way is so effective?

Comment: Just trying to understand and am curious about the original motivation. The CLR does seem to be a nice design, and is definitely paying off now that Microsoft is open-sourcing .NET technologies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My understanding is that part of the point of the JVM was that the code could "run anywhere", but CLR code was designed to run only on Windows

"Windows" is not a synonym for "x86" - even back in the late-1990s Windows ran on DEC Alpha, MIPS, x86, and even PowerPC and by the early-2000s when .NET 1.1 was released Windows also supported IA-64 (Itanium) and AMD64 was on the horizon, while Windows CE (the then-dominant smart-device OS) ran on x86, ARM, SH-3 and MIPS. The case for a cross-platform, JIT-compiled runtime exclusively for Windows was (and remains) still quite convincing.

Granted, we can only speculate on the reasoning behind the CLR's development, but many strong reasons can be deduced from history:

Java was the first multiplatform VM (and library, complete with GUI and web-server packages) to take-off - but Microsoft didn't control it and their attempts at extending the platform for their benefit didn't work out (see "J++") - if Microsoft couldn't capture the new generation of Java programmers (who saw VB as below them, and who didn't want to mess-around with C/C++) then they would lose control of the desktop software ecosystem: why buy Windows if desktop software works fine on Mac, Solaris, etc?

On the server-side, "Classic" ASP 3.0 was getting upstaged by PHP and JSP - Microsoft could have invested time in improving ASP separately, but they decided to make ASP.NET (then called "ASP+") an integral part of the .NET Framework too: this was a boon for developers because it enabled object-level code-reuse, something that was previously impossible (e.g. using C++ classes in VB) or very difficult (using COM/DCOM).

So the CLR offers 3 main benefits over the contemporary status-quo:

- Cross-platform support that enables the same compiled binary to run on different physical architectures and operating systems (x86 vs ARM, Desktop vs Handheld)
- A platform more sophisticated than VB, without the hassle and learning-curve of C/C++
- True code reuse

And a number of proprietary advantages for Microsoft:

- Provides a competitive-offering compared to Java in an effort to keep itself relevant in the developer ecosystem
- By controlling the platform, they ensure vendor lock-in - but pragmatically it means they can ensure it is kept updated and in lock-step with the underlying platform. It sucks when something cool comes along (e.g. hardware-accelerated cryptography) but it won't be supported for months, possibly years, in Java because of the effort required to get everyone on-board and to add support (possibly emulation) for platforms that don't support it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a way for designing modern compilers, that is, having a `front-end` that is separate from the `backend`.

The `front-end` compiler translates the language to an intermediate language that the backend can pick and compile to native.

This makes the complier modular where it is easier to switch between backend implementations. In Java for instance, there are too many JVMs, and the reason why they exist is because `javac` knows nothing about them, it just produces byte-code that the VM can process.

In .Net for example, C# and VB.Net produce IL that the CLR can compile and run. This means that Microsoft have built a VM for any language that produces IL.

Back to Java, there are too many JVM languages. Why do you think it is the case? Because the language designer doesn't need to care about  writing a VM which is very hard, they can design their language, compile to IL and get it run on any VM.

Having the VM or the backend is completely separate module is so beneficial, you can have teams working on the backend doing code optimizations, JITing, GC, etc.. and others working on the language design.

However, I think GC is an exception here, where I think the language should know whether a GC exists or not (I am not aware of a language that allows to you turn the GC off), but thats the only thing the language needs to know, in Java for instance you can switch between GC implementation with few program arguments. Isn't that awesome?

......

Comment: LLVM has the same modern infrastructure that you described (i.e. frontend/backend), but without requiring a VM.

Comment: Your third paragraph seems contradictory.  The whole point of the JVM is to have one language for many platforms.  When you say "too many JVMs," do you really mean "as many as you want?"

Comment: You said "the backend can pick and compile to native" - but the CLR only targeted a single native instruction set originally. Also, I'd disagree that the Go compiler isn't "modern."

Comment: @mheiber I said "a way" and not "the way" :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I didn't realize that LLVM is not a virtual machine until I read your comment and [looked it up](http://llvm.org/) - cool!

Comment: @RobertHarvey I meant, developing different JVMs implementations is easier

Comment: @SleimanJneidi, I edited your post to say "a way" since you were missing the "a" before. Not trying to nitpick, just want to make your intended meaning clearer.